# Changing colors of ContourPlot

Tags: plotting, color

I have a problem with ContourPlot colors. In fact, i have the following table

```
A={x^2 + y^2 == 203.378, x^2 + y^2 == 59.1222, x^2 + y^2 == 35.2762, x^2 + y^2 == 25.4656, x^2 + y^2 == 20.1073, x^2 + y^2 == 16.7197,  x^2 + y^2 == 14.37, x^2 + y^2 == 12.6233, x^2 + y^2 == 11.2367,  x^2 + y^2 == 10.0089}
```

That i want to plot using the colors of "ThermometerColors". To do so, i used the following

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@A, {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, ColorFunction -> "ThermometerColors"]
```

However, all the plots have the same color. I think that ContourPlot associates only the first color to the functions of table A. Any idea how to associate one color from "ThermometerColors" to each function?

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[A], {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, ContourStyle -> MapIndexed[{ColorData["ThermometerColors"][#2[[1]]/Length[A]]} &, A], PlotLegends -> A[[All, -1]], FrameStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

If we reverse the color order:

```
 ContourPlot[Evaluate[A], {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, ContourStyle -> Reverse@MapIndexed[{ColorData["ThermometerColors"][#2[[1]]/Length[A]]} &, A], PlotLegends -> A[[All, -1]], FrameStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you want contour colors to reflect contour values:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate @ A[[1, 1]], {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, 
  ContourShading -> None, 
  Contours -> Thread[{A[[All, -1]], 
    ColorData["ThermometerColors"] /@ Rescale[A[[All, -1]]]}],
  PlotLegends -> Sort @ A[[All, -1]]]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate @ A[[1, 1]], {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, 
  ContourShading -> None, 
  Contours -> Thread[{A[[All, -1]], 
     ColorData[{"ThermometerColors", MinMax@A[[All, -1]]}] /@ A[[All, -1]]}], 
  PlotLegends -> Sort @ A[[All, -1]]]
```

> same picture

Answer (score 6):

```
$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

A = {x^2 + y^2 == 203.378, x^2 + y^2 == 59.1222, x^2 + y^2 == 35.2762,
    x^2 + y^2 == 25.4656, x^2 + y^2 == 20.1073, x^2 + y^2 == 16.7197, 
   x^2 + y^2 == 14.37, x^2 + y^2 == 12.6233, x^2 + y^2 == 11.2367, 
   x^2 + y^2 == 10.0089};

ContourPlot[Evaluate@A[[1, 1]],
 {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15},
 Contours -> A[[All, 2]],
 ContourShading -> None,
 ContourStyle -> (ColorData["ThermometerColors"] /@
    Subdivide[Length[A] - 1]),
 PlotLegends -> A[[All, 2]]]
```

[image]